# Change attribute of class for a given time

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to code the following situation and if so, could you please tell me how to do it?

Let's assume we have a function `setAttributeForTenSec()`, which sets an attribute in a class for 10 seconds (this means that, for 10 seconds, the attribute is changed and then it is set back to its initial value). Let's assume I have another function in the same class called `useAttribute()` which uses the attribute that has been set. In the `main()` if I call `setAttributeForTenSec()` and then call `useAttribute()`, then `useAttribute()` must use the updated value of the attribute if it hasn't been 10 seconds, If yes, then it has to use the initial value of the attribute

I haven't been able to do it, because I don't know how (I actually, as I've said, am not sure if it's possible)

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Well, I'm writing a game where a player might use a shield that lasts for 10 seconds. While shielded, he cannot take damage. But after 10 seconds, the shield must disappear

Comment: What framework are you using to develop this game? It probably provides a timer/animation class which could be used for this.

Comment: I am not using any particular framework. I am just trying to write an App on Android Studio in Java

Comment: If not using a framework with time checking built in already, then you may want to check out some of the various classes in Java's [Time Library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). It has all kinds of functionality you can use for this.

Comment: The basic principle, you mark a point in time when the shield activates. Then as your game runs through it's update loop, it checks the current time against that marker and acts appropriately until the check time is equal to or after some amount of time to act differently.

Comment: There are many ways to do that and they all depend on the current implementaiton of the logic. Please add the relevant code to your question so we can help you better.